# Preserve formatting long (> 15 characters) numbers

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to get columns from other excel workbook

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""C:\Book1.xlsx""), null, true),"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Sheet1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Everything ok except formatting? PreserveFormatting not work as in source numbers stored as text and in destination they comes as floated numbers. Nothings change the format nor `.ListObject.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "@"` nor `ActiveSheets.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"`, format is changing but number left in format 42342352+15e

So how to bring long numbers from source to destination?

Comment: Do you want the format to remain text? In that case, you can maybe set the formatting to "0" and then add a apostrophe at the start of the value.

Comment: I cant, beacause Excel auto rounding all numbers

Comment: You need to `Transform` the data to text in your `Queries.Add` formula (i.e. before it gets to the worksheet).

Comment: how? it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating data as text
Use this one when you want to treat all data in the file as text, overriding Excels column type "General" to guess what type of data is in the column.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

If you want to read the column headers into the result set (using HDR=NO even though there is a header) and the column data is numeric, use IMEX=1 to avoid crash.

To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data columns. Consider the scenario that one Excel file might work fine cause that file's data causes the driver to guess one data type while another file, containing other data, causes the driver to guess another data type. This can cause your app to crash.